# Ruby on Rails Scope with params and SQL in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone please tell me what is wrong in this statement?

```
scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do
where('(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)', sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
```

end

NetBeans put a red line under it and says Unexpected tLPAREN_ARG

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using older version of ruby (1.9), it fails with that error message as you can't put space before the parameters in lambda call. May be your Netbeans setup has syntax checker for Ruby 1.9 configured. So the correct syntax for Ruby 1.9 should be:

```
scope :between, ->(sender_id, recipient_id) do
   where('(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)', sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
end
```

Check the space between -> & (sender_id, recipient_id)

But your code should work with Ruby 2.0 and above.